# Wampserver cache clearing

Tags: caching, wampserver

I'm using wampserver for my php apps.
And mPdf is used for generating PDF files. But here's the problem,
even if I modify the .css file for the generated PDF file style, it won's be applied
until I delete all the PDF files already generated for certain pages in the DATA cache folder.

So my question is just, how often does wampserver clear its cache folder and drop the temp files?

Comment: have you tried clearing your browsers cache instead of the servers?

Comment: To clear your browsers cache its normally CTRL+F5

Comment: Well thanks, as you said, I had to manually clear the cache files on the server side. But by the way, any idea for modifying the frequency of server cache clearing?

Comment: I would suggest turning off the cache on your development server completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks  for all of the suggestions, it turned out not to be the problem of WampServer but the app that I've installed in my project dokuwiki(dw2pdf).

So there's an option not to keep the generated pdf in the cache, or you can also clean it manually at the server side.

Thanks anyway.